# Which data structure is implemented to manage files and folders in mobiles?

Tags: android, data-structures

Trees are generally used for managing data but which particular type of trees are used?

Comment: To represent it on the filesystem?  Its just a tree, the individual details of how the tree is stored depends on the filesystem.  You wouldn't need (or want) to depend on individual file system details.  Nor would they match any type of tree you'd be expecting, as the needs of a tree for permanent storage and efficient reading from magnetic disk or flash  are different than an in memory data structure.

Comment: Take a look of [B tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and its variants.

Answer (score 1):

A typical memory representation of a file directory tree looks something like this:

```
class Directory
    string Name
    List<Directory> Directories
    List<string> Files
```

Briefly, a `Directory` contains two types of child nodes: files and directories. You can represent the files as strings, or if you want more information you can create a `File` class of some kind. A `Directory`, of course, is a recursive data structure.

To traverse the thing, you write something like this:

```
TraverseDirectory(Directory d)
    output d.Name
    for each file in d.Files
        output file // it's a string
    for each Directory subdir in d.Directories
        TraverseDirectory(subdir)
```

Convert to your favorite language, modify as desired.